# How to calculate the birth date ? And sum of digits of n?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

Naga was born in the year 19n. ‘n’ is a two digit number. In the year 2014 he completed ‘n’ years﻿  of his age. 
The sum of the two digits of ‘n’ is-

Let Naga was born -19XY
Then how to corelate the value of n to find answer??.

Comment: Hint: What is the expression from which you can calculate his age (in 2014)? We know that it's $n$, but is there another way to express it?

Comment: As you can see, "the year 19n [where] ‘n’ is a two digit number" is a non-standard mathematical notation that is difficult to do arithmetic with. Can you rewrite it as a regular mathematical expression that you can do arithmetic with?

Comment: I am thinking  and taken it as n×n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2014 - n = 1900 + n and solve for n.